# Blocks overlapping in css

Tags: html, css

I have 2 blocks within a block that needs to be displayed-inline but it does not work when I give display-inline.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8T5RZ/

I need the 2 blocks to be displayed side by side instead of overlapping

HTML:

```
<div class="outer-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
        <div class="innermost-container" />
        <div class="innermost-container" />

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.innermost-container{
    background-color:green;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
}
```

Comment: You can't self-close div tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<div class="innermost-container" />
```

to

```
<div class="innermost-container"></div>
```

`<div />` is not valid HTML markup.

Write:

```
.innermost-container{display:inline-block;}
```

Note:

`inline-block` leavers white-space between elements. Write elements on same line to avoid white-space.

write:

```
<div class="innermost-container"></div><div class="innermost-container"></div>
```

instead of

```
<div class="innermost-container"></div>
<div class="innermost-container"></div>
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/8T5RZ/5/)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot self close a `div` element. Even though they are empty, you need to explicitly have a closing `</div>` tag. So close them and than use `display: inline-block;` for `.innermost-container`

```
.innermost-container{
    background-color:green;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
    display: inline-block; /* Can also use float */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8T5RZ/2/)

---

Henceforth, you can use [this](http://validator.w3.org/) tool to validate your markup.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can't self-close div tags (`<div />`) and 2) set the display property of your divs to inline-block:

```
display:inline-block;
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8T5RZ/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

`Display:inline` would not care about dimensions, so it would wrap on content: http://jsfiddle.net/8T5RZ/7/